# How to run different test classes in different assembly sequentially by Azure pipeline and MsTest?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-pipelines, mstest

We are using azure pipeline to run our unit tests, the yml file is like below:

[image]

But there are two test cases in two `separate` dlls which overlaps each other and cause race condition, say Test1 in assembly1 and Test2 in assembly2 are calling the same api and modifying the same resource at the same time.

we use MsTest as a test framework and our tests are decorated with different `TestCategory` attribute.

Is there any way to make these two test classes dependent to each other without moving them to the same assembly?

Comment: You can run your test classes in two "VSTest" tasks separately, and use `testFiltercriteria` to filter the currently running tests based on `TestCategory`. For example, `testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=CategoryA'`.

Comment: Thanks @ZiyangLiu-MSFT i want something automated, should i change yml file?

Comment: You can define a parameter and set the value to one of your TestCategory in your main yaml. Then pass the value of this parameter to your template. Set `testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory!=CategoryA'` in your first VSTest task and set `testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=CategoryA'` in your second VSTest Task.